# Abrir pagina en segundo plano oculta

Tags: javascript, popup

Busco alguna idea de por que este código:

```
var urlpopup = "http://googl.com";
function myClickHandler() {
        if(web == true)
        setTimeout('popup(urlpopup)', 200);
    }
    //funcion para mostrar el popup 
    function popup(url){
        params = 'width='+screen.width;
        params += ', height='+screen.height;
        params += ', top=0, left=0'
        params += ', fullscreen=yes'
        params += ',_parent'
        params += ',channelmode=0'
        params += ',directories=0'
        params += ',location=0'
        params += ',menubar=0'
        params += ',resizable=0'
        params += ',status=0';
        var pu = window.open(url,'Rollassage', params);
        pu.blur()
        window.focus();
        return false;
    }
```

que se supone abre una ventana en segundo plano no lo hace; la ventana con la url de

> google.com

aparece en primer plano, no detrás de la pagina principal.

Comment: abuso de la técnica de popunder hace que ya no sea tan fácil hacerlo.

Comment: Si te entiendo pero igual es curiosidad y una pregunta que aun no entiendo. Por que e visto que algunos sitios sulen usarla y les funciona bien. Y desconosco como se hace

Comment: Tiene un ejemplo? Creo que Chrome previene "pop-under" ventanas..

Comment: ¿Has probado con otros navegadores?

Answer (score 0):

Puedes intentar con el siguiente codigo. Test hecho en chrome v70.

```
window.open('http://google.com','','height=1000,width=1000');
window.open().close();
```

Comment: Aunque no haria planes de usar este codigo por mucho mas tiempo o en un proyecto serio, la politica de chrome acerca de los pop-unders es clara, y probablemente en una version proxima esta solucion quede invalida.

Comment: efectivamente ese método funciona bien lo único malo es que no esconde el pop-unders solo lo elimina

Answer (score 0):

Por que esta mal programado.

Aca se esta llamando a una variable "web", no definida.

```
   if(web == true)
```

Y por ultimo de todo, son declaraciones de funciones que tampoco se estan invocando, faltaria un:

```
myClickHandler();
```

Saludos.